# Calling JavaScript function from codebehind many times / recursively

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if it is possible to keep calling a function in `JavaScript` many times in codebehind `(asp.net WebForm)` with different parameters and return values, for example I have this `JavaScript` function that is called `Add(x,y)` that returns the sum and I want to call it again with different parameters.

Note: The function name is just an example

Answer (score 1):

Use Clientscript.RegisterClientScriptBlock for multiple call like

```
  ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
  StringBuilder csText = new StringBuilder();
  csText.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\"> ");
  csText.Append("result1=Add(x,y);");
  csText.Append("result2=Add(result1,b);");
  csText.Append("</script>");
  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, csName, csText.ToString());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks and about the return value of each function ? how can i get them

Comment: updated code but better to wrap in plain JS code & use call.

Comment: what i had in mind after you did csText.Append("Add(x,y);"); i wanted to take that return value then do for example a switch case on it then based on that i'll call the add function with different parameters

Comment: if you want to use result on server side, then its not possible that way
you cant write your code to work compositely server + client side. some thing problem with your requirement.

Comment: Asp,net holds control only up to execute javascript through code behind, can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: it is not a requirement i was just asking if it is possible to do it or not as @MukeshChudasama suggested i'll put my whole code in one Function

Comment: you can 
catch result on java script 
then call Ajax to pass that result do server side manipulations 
return result on client side & use it for further

Comment: you can mark as answer if it satisfied your question.